# Envio de correos electronicos con Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Estoy atrancado con esto, tengo el siguiente controlador:

```
function prueba_envio_email()
 {
    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'micuentadecorreo@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'micontrasena'
    );

    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('micuentadecorreo@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to('micuentadecorreo@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Email test');
    $this->email->message('It is working!');

    if ($this->email->send())
    {
        echo "email enviado";
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }

 }
```

Siguiendo un tutorial de youtube, he modificado un par de archivos.

php.ini y sendmail.ini de la carpeta XAMPP.

Del sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
auth_username=micuentadecorreo@gmail.com
auth_password=micontrasena
```

Y del php.ini

```
sendmail_path="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" -t"
```

También he probado a enviarlo con el puerto 465, que lo había visto en otro sitio.

Y he probado a hacerlo de dos formas, usando el controlador de codeigniter y usando un archivo php simple con este contenido:

```
<?php

$message = "hola que tal estas";
$headers = "From: micorreoelectronico@gmail.com";
mail("micorreoelectronico","Testing", $message, $headers);
echo "test hecho por mi";

?>
```

Al final consigo que el controlador me devuelva el mensaje de que se ha enviado el correo, tanto el "autoenvio" a mi correo de gmail como a otro que tengo de hotmail pero no me llega nada.

He mirado tambien algunos post del foro pero hay información diversa y difusa. O eso creo.

¿Alguien que haya trabajado con esto sabe por donde pueden ir los tiros? Gracias.

Comment: Gmail exige usar TLS, así que tu instalación debe incluir la librería correspondiente.

Comment: Supuestamente, codeigniter, en su clase para envio, puedes usar TLS a traves de smtp_crypto=>'tls' pero tampoco me ha funcionado.

Comment: Hola, a mi me funciona la librería de correo de codeigniter perfectamente, tal vez deberías cambiar la linea `$this->load->library('email',$config);` por las lineas `$this->load->library("email");` y `$this->email->initialize($config);`. Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Hola, ¿lo estas haciendo todo desde localhost o estas usando algún servidor pagado?

Comment: @ZocrateZ En la empresa donde trabajo tienen el servidor de correo integrado a su servidor propio y funciona desde _localhost_ como desde el servidor